# Get all table values if match in 2 other tables exists

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

I have a table "channel".

```
channelId
a
b
c
d
```

a table "video"

```
videoId | channelId
1       | a
2       | b
3       | c
4       | e
```

a table "comment"

```
commentID | videoID | videoID_channelID
xx        | 1       | a
yy        | 2       | b
zz        | 5       | e
tt        | 6       | f
```

Keys are:

- channel.channelId = video.channelId = comment.videoID_channelID
- video.videoId = comment.videoID

I need:

- all channels with at least 1 video and 1 comment
- all videos with at least 1 channel and 1 comment
- all comments with a video and a channel

So I want to do 3 SQL statements, one for each table that references the other 2.

I tried it with a double inner-join (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/) but it seems to return all combinations that fit rather than:

```
channelId
a
b

videoId | channelId
1       | a
2       | b

commentID | videoID | videoID_channelID
xx        | 1       | a
yy        | 2       | b
```

My code so far to get all channels with at least 1 video and 1 comment:

```
SELECT
        channel.channelId
FROM
    channel
    INNER JOIN video ON video.channelId = channel.channelId
    INNER JOIN comment ON comment.videoID_channelID = video.channelId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the results that you want with the same query that joins all 3 tables, but for each case select different columns:

```
SELECT c.channelId
FROM channel c
INNER JOIN video v ON v.channelId = c.channelId
INNER JOIN comment cm ON cm.videoID_channelID = v.channelId;

SELECT v.videoID, c.channelId
FROM channel c
INNER JOIN video v ON v.channelId = c.channelId
INNER JOIN comment cm ON cm.videoID_channelID = v.channelId;

SELECT cm.commentID, v.videoID, c.channelId
FROM channel c
INNER JOIN video v ON v.channelId = c.channelId
INNER JOIN comment cm ON cm.videoID_channelID = v.channelId;
```

You may have to add DISTINCT after each SELECT if you get duplicates in your actual data.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/byn9E9uGz1Ckp93qDxhHPE/1).
Results:

```
| channelId |
| --------- |
| a         |
| b         |


| videoID | channelId |
| ------- | --------- |
| 1       | a         |
| 2       | b         |


| commentID | videoID | channelId |
| --------- | ------- | --------- |
| xx        | 1       | a         |
| yy        | 2       | b         |
```

Comment: If I run the first query I get 229718696 results but I only have 63 channels? Something doesn't work right.

Comment: Did you add DISTINCT after SELECT?

Comment: I did know and it works, thought I only need it if I use multiple SELECT statements like in your example. First query took 32 minutes (63 channels, 12.000 videos, 454.000 comments). Any way to speed that up?

Comment: Make sure that all columns that you base your joins on are indexed:  video.channelId, channel.channelId and comment.videoID_channelID.

Comment: I create the SQL tables with pandas pd.read_excel, do stuff, df.to_sql, haven't found a way to create a primary key in the function this way.

Comment: I don't know about pandas but you can find what you need about the creation of indexes here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. Why do you always SELECT from channel c though? Shouldn't for video SELECT video v and for comments SELECT comment cm be selected?

Comment: Since there are only INNER joins there is no difference in the results. You can change the order of the joins if you think this would make it more readable. Also sometimes by changing the order of the joins the optimizer may (or not) choose a different plan for the query that could be more (or less) efficient. You can experiment.

Comment: I noticed that some videos don't have comments. Do I need to check for cm.videoId = v.videoId in addition? So last line = "INNER JOIN comments cm ON cm.channelId = v.channelId and cm.videoId = v.videoId"?

Comment: This depends on which condition you want to base the join of the tables `video` and `comment`. I saw in your code that the condition is: `cm.videoID_channelID = v.channelId` and I kept it. If you want you can change it to `cm.videoId = v.videoId` or use both combined with AND or OR operators.