# Inner join for multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, inner-join

Same question as [Get all table values if match in 2 other tables exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774266/get-all-table-values-if-match-in-2-other-tables-exists/59774646) but trying to to the same in Python/pandas because I can't set PK/FK in pandas when writing to SQLite DB (df.to_sql has no API to do so), making SQL too slow.

I have a dataframe "channel".

```
channelId
a
b
c
d
```

a dataframe "video"

```
videoId | channelId
1       | a
2       | b
3       | c
4       | e
```

a dataframe "comment"

```
commentID | videoID | videoID_channelID
xx        | 1       | a
yy        | 2       | b
zz        | 5       | e
tt        | 6       | f
```

Keys are:

- channel.channelId = video.channelId = comment.videoID_channelID
- video.videoId = comment.videoID

I need:

- all channels with at least 1 video and 1 comment
- all videos with at least 1 channel and 1 comment
- all comments with a video and a channel

So I want to do 3 inner joins, one for each dataframe that references the other 2.

```
channelId
a
b

videoId | channelId
1       | a
2       | b

commentID | videoID | videoID_channelID
xx        | 1       | a
yy        | 2       | b
```

I know I can do an inner join for 2 dataframes like:

```
pd.merge(channel, video, left_on='channelId', right_on='channelId', how='inner')
```

But how can I do it for 3 data frames with different indexes?

Comment: How about merge twice ~

Comment: What comment above suggests, and for the first join you can rewrite your code more concise: `channel.merge(video, on='channelId')`, because they both have the same key column, and `inner` join is the default.

Comment: So your whole code would be: `channel.merge(video, on='channelId').merge(comment, left_on=['channelId', 'videoId'], right_on=['videoID', 'videoID_channelID']`

Comment: That merge gives me all columns from all 3 dataframes but not the the single dataframes with only the columns from that dataframe that I need?